# How to display data in grid view column wise flutter not row wise

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-gridview

I want display data in gridview column wise from first column bottom to top , second column bottom top top  and so on . But not row wise in flutter and also need to calculate the height of the dynamical gridview can any one help me

```
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02,
                child: GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 1,
                      childAspectRatio: defaultAspectRatio,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 0.5,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 0.5),
                  itemCount: resultArray.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                    return ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints:
                          BoxConstraints.tight(const Size(250.0, 150.0)),
                      child: Container(
                        child: InkWell(
                          child: MouseRegion(
                            child: Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(resultArray[index].toString()),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

[image]

Comment: Add your current result image

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil please check the image